# What is the default time zone in Joda DateTimeFormatter if time zone is not specified?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm not familiar with Joda DateTimeFormatter, so I'm wondering if there is no time zone specified for DateTimeFormatter, what will be the default time zone? For example I have:

```
DateTimeFormatter stdFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime today = stdFormatter.parseDateTime("07/20/2017");
```

In this case, what would be the time zone of `today`? Is it gonna be 2017-07-20 00:00:00 UTC by default? Thank you!

Comment: System default mb?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see what you get? That is called **research**, and you should always do your own research before posting a question on here. Down-voted because "this question does not show any research effort" *(from tooltip of down-vote button)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the `DateTime` documentation [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), the DateTime internally stores the value as milliseconds past 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, where Z is the UTC zone.

The way it is output depends on how you decide to format it (i.e. if you want to print the DateTime in a different time zone, you can use the Joda libraries to do so).

In this case, `DateTimeFormat.forPattern` uses the JVM default locale, which is determined by `Locale.getDefault()`, whatever that may be for you. So, your DateTime will contain the time at UTC for `'07/20/2017 00:00:00 {YOUR TIME ZONE}'`.

Say your time zone is PDT (i.e. UTC-7). Then "07/20/2017 00:00:00 PDT" == "07/20/2017 07:00:00 UTC". Your DateTime object will store that UTC time.